# Making flash valid

Tags: html, flash, validation, noscript

How could I make this section of code valid?  I have not had much experience with flash embedment.

```
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="999" height="241" title="">
      <param name="movie" value="images/banner.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="BGCOLOR" value="#EFE8DE" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <embed src="images/banner.swf" width="999" height="241" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"</embed></object>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not using [`swfobject`](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting in your question. It should give it away.

```
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="//download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="999" height="241" title="">
        <param name="movie" value="images/banner.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#efe8de" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <embed src="images/banner.swf" width="999" height="241" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler,  I have put your fixed code across however I am still getting that its not valid.  My doctype is <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: the `<embed>` element is deprecated in XHTML 1.0 which is causing all of the errors. Also, I second using swfobject.

Comment: Thanks, Could you provide an example Tyler?